# App Check log FirebaseException: Too many attempts

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

I am trying to request the app token but I always get this error:

`Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.` and also this :
`W/StorageUtil(24781): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.`

Below is the code where I request the token which I would like to save globally but cannot quite receive. This is the code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();

    try {
      // Ottieni il token di App Check
      var appCheckToken = await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.getToken();
      if (appCheckToken != null) {
          CheckToken = appCheckToken;

        print("questo è il cane bastardo: $CheckToken");
      } else {
        print("Il token di App Check è nullo");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Errore nell'ottenere il token di App Check: $e");
    }

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CartModel()),
        // Altri provider se necessario...
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to adjust the quota section under Authentication > settings

[image]